# double form refresh

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm new to PHP and Javascript, and just starting a website that will have two forms, one form with 5 checkboxes, and one with 5 radiobuttons. When you change the radiobuttons selected radiobutton it refreshes the page and uses the new value. The same with the checkboxes. Unfortunately, if you change one of the forms, and then change another form, the 1st forms value will no longer be there.

Here's the code:

```
<form name='form2' method='post'>
           <input type="radio" name="group1" value="all" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if ($_REQUEST['group1'] == null || $_REQUEST['group1'] == "all"){ echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> All<br>
           <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Example" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if ($_REQUEST['group1'] == "Example"){ echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> Example<br>
           <input type="radio" name="group1" value="clifton" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if ($_REQUEST['group1'] == "clifton"){ echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> Clifton<br/>
           <input type="radio" name="group1" value="fruita" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if ($_REQUEST['group1'] == "fruita"){ echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> Fruita<br/>
           <input type="radio" name="group1" value="loma" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if ($_REQUEST['group1'] == "loma"){ echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> Loma<br/>
       </form>


       <form name='form3' method='post'>
           <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="smoking" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option1'])){ echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/> No Smoking<br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="kids" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option2'])){ echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/>Good for Kids<br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="wheelchair" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option3'])){ echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/>Wheelchair Accessible<br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="alcohol" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option4'])){ echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/>Serves Alcohol<br>
           <input type="checkbox" name="option5" value="delivery" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option5'])){ echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/>Delivery Servicee<br>  
       </form>
```

I'm trying to get both forms input to be preserved even when the other form changes.
Any help will be GLADLY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have described a problem, but where's the question?

Comment: Can't speak for them, but I think OP wants both sets of inputs to preserve their values.

Comment: oops sorry @machineghost is correct... I will update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to use AJAX. But you can also add hidden input fields to both forms corresponding to the values in the opposite form:

```
<form name='form2' method='post'>
       <input type="radio" name="group1" value="all" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if ($_REQUEST['group1'] == null || $_REQUEST['group1'] == "all"){ echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> All<br>
       <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Example" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if ($_REQUEST['group1'] == "Example"){ echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> Example<br>
       <input type="radio" name="group1" value="clifton" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if ($_REQUEST['group1'] == "clifton"){ echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> Clifton<br/>
       <input type="radio" name="group1" value="fruita" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if ($_REQUEST['group1'] == "fruita"){ echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> Fruita<br/>
       <input type="radio" name="group1" value="loma" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if ($_REQUEST['group1'] == "loma"){ echo "checked='checked'";}?>/> Loma<br/>
    <?php foreach( range( 1, 5) as $i): ?>
        <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option' . $i])): ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="option<?php echo $i; ?>" value="1" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</form>


<form name='form3' method='post'>
       <input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="smoking" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option1'])){ echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/> No Smoking<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="kids" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option2'])){ echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/>Good for Kids<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="option3" value="wheelchair" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option3'])){ echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/>Wheelchair Accessible<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="option4" value="alcohol" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option4'])){ echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/>Serves Alcohol<br>
       <input type="checkbox" name="option5" value="delivery" onClick="if (this.checked) this.form.submit();" <?php if(isset($_REQUEST['option5'])){ echo "checked='checked'";} ?>/>Delivery Servicee<br>  
       <input type="hidden" name="group1" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['group1']) ? $_REQUEST['group1'] : 'all'); ?>" />
</form>
```

**Edit:** [Here is a demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lNVp2P) showing it working.

Answer (score 0):

you have to join this inputs in one form element, form elements submit only the information of their input fields and can't send the data of other form element unless you prevent the default form submit action and make your own call via ajax

Answer (score 0):

So, you're missing all the server-side code here, but I can explain the basic problem and hopefully that will allow you to solve it.

You have two forms, form2 and form3.  When you submit form2, it doesn't submit form3's data, and vice versa.  So, when your server sends back the new page (the one you see post-submit) it doesn't have the data from the other form reflected in it.

What you need to do is send the data from both forms along.  The simplest way to do this would be to just use one form, but if you want to get fancy you could combine their values via JS, or even submit them both via AJAX.